# `var = something rescue nil` behaviour

Tags: ruby, exception

In Ruby you can write a `rescue` at the end of an assignment to catch any errors that might come up. I have a function (below: `a_function_that_may_fail`) where it's convenient to let it throw an error if certain conditions aren't met. The following code works well

```
post = {}
# Other Hash stuff
post['Caption'] = a_function_that_may_fail rescue nil
```

However I'd like to have post['Caption'] not even set if the function fails.

I know I can do:

```
begin
  post['Caption'] = a_function_that_may_fail
rescue
end
```

but that feels a little excessive - is there a simpler solution?

Comment: Rewriting the function isn't really an option, its a Nokogiri search -- essentially I want to set the 'Caption' Hash item if there is a specific XML element, but importantly, not set it if that XML element isn't there.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problem is precedence. The simplest solution:

```
(post['Caption'] = a_function_that_may_fail) rescue nil
```

Changing the precedence like this is a little esoteric, though. It would probably be better if you can rewrite your `a_function_that_may_fail` to return `nil` if it fails.

You could also use a temporary variable and test for nilness:

```
caption = a_function_that_may_fail rescue nil
post['Caption'] = caption unless caption.nil?
```

A really minor difference is that this does not set `post['Caption']` if `a_function_that_may_fail` did not raise an exception but returned `nil`.

Comment: (...) rescue nil is not that esoteric, imho. It's easy to read too.

Answer (score 3):

```
post.store('Caption', a_function_that_may_fail) rescue nil
```

Comment: Cute, but won't apply if instead of post['Caption']= it was local_var=. I much prefer molf's "esoteric" solution

Answer (score 2):

make sure your method returns either `nil` or `false`:

```
def this_may_fail
  some_logic rescue nil
end
```

you can then use the if modifier to check the return value of your method and assign the value only if it's not `nil` or `false`:

```
post['Caption'] = this_may_fail if this_may_fail
```

or you can cache the return value of `this_may_fail` in a local variable if you don't like to call the method twice for the if condition and assignment.

```
the_value = this_may_fail
post['Caption'] = the_value if the_value
```

also notice that the `rescue` modifier only catches `StandardError` and its subclasses.